# Safety question for defrosting and refreezing chicken breasts

Tags: food-safety

I want to defrost a bulk bag of boneless chicken breasts....while they are still VERY cold I want to marinade them and refreeze to use in a few days and have them already in the marinade to save me time....can i do this without a problem? The marinade has EVOO and lemoin juice, and spices.

Comment: My rule: Freeze once, defrost once.
Apart from that: Marinating is a "living" process, not a frozen one. Frozen marinade on frozen meat doesn't achieve anything.

Answer (score 0):

One should only defrost once. Refreezing defrosted proteins results in loss of texture and flavor (regardless of the marinade.) The acidic component of your marinade is not enough to stave off the possibility of bacterial contamination. Why not just defrost your chicken breasts, place them in the marinade, and cook them off after several hours. You could re-heat them later.